# Android Dex: [ActivityName] Unable to execute DX

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-support-library

When i compile my project i'm given this kind of errors ;

> Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] Unable to execute DX
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
>   Error:Android Dex: [OdeAl] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)

How can i fix this errors?

Comment: you probably have repeating jar files with different names that have the function name in the error defined. meaning if there are two jars,both of them contain the same classes/packages

Comment: Do you have any library project attached with your main project?

Comment: @InnocentKiller yes i attached support-v4 and support-v7 app compat library

Comment: Then remove android support v4.jar from your main project and add it the jar file from your external library and then try.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is you have multiple imports of the same `Library` OR `Class` .

Actually, the error is saying that you have :

> Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImp

**So**, you should check whether you added same jar files more than once.
If yes,Remove any one of them from libs folder and clean your project.

Comment: i had this problem , i added libs directory and added one other jar file to update my app , so remove all items from library list and add them again with no multiple import

Answer (score 1):

like [@Josef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081827/josef) answer , you can known what is `jar` file which had imported two time or more into android project **From** The error

Next Line into your Error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 

Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionI
```

That mean `android-support-v4.jar` file which had been imported twice or more into android project